# Change the color of a single list item

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is there a way in HTML/CSS to change color of just one list item not all of them? I just want to change the color of each of them so the user knows what page he is on. for now I managed only to do the `a:hover` but I cant figure out how could I do it so the color would stay.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul id="buttons">
        <li><a href="index.html">| About</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/gallery.html">| Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/prices.html">| Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/faq.html">| FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/contact_us.html">| Contact Us</a></li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#buttons {
background-color: black;
}

.clear { clear: both; }

#buttons li a
{
position:block;
color:#fff;
padding:1em;
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
width:95px;
}

#buttons li a:hover
{
background-color:#bc1b32;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way would be to just create a class, lets say selected, add it to the a tag you'd like to change the color of, and that's it:

```
.selected { background-color: green; }
```

then your link would be:

```
<li><a class='selected' href="index.html">| About</a></li>
```

Comment: This also assumes that you don't have an included navigation.  If you have navigation code in every single one of your pages, this is simple.  If you use a separate file for your navigation you can use any of the examples below.

Answer (score 3):

Look: http://jsfiddle.net/qzXgJ/

Detail:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
        <li><a id="index" href="#">| About</a></li>
        <li><a id="gallery" href="#">| Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a id="prices" href="#">| Prices</a></li>
        <li><a id="faq" href="#">| FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a id="contact_us" href="#">| Contact Us</a></li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>​​​
```

**JS**

```
$(".wrapper li a").click(function () {

    $('.wrapper li a').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

    $(this).addClass('selected');

    $(".wrapper ul li a").click(function () {

    $('.wrapper ul li a').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

    $(this).addClass('selected');

    console.log($(this).attr('id'));

    /* Get html by jQuery */ 
    $.get($(this).attr('id'),function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

**CSS**

```
.selected
{
    background-color:#b51ba2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this answer for the same question with good results: http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css

Answer (score -1):

The question is a little vague; to indicate which page the user is on you could add a class to that particular list item that houses the link they last clicked:

```
<li class="current">
    <a href="html/prices.html">| Prices</a>
</li>
```

You then provide specific styles for that:

```
li.current {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```